# Paint Shop Pro 7: where to find color:transparent?

Tags: color, corel-paint-shop-pro

In a .png image, I want to color the three far-northwest corner pixels, now colored white, so they are transparent.

This is, I want the background color to show through those pixels. But I can't find in PSP7 where to pick up transparent color with the eyedropper.

Can you tell me how to color those pixels transparent?

Comment: you want to color those white blocks? or blue blocks?

Comment: @Jack -- I want to make the white pixels display as transparent on the rendered web page.

Comment: wherever i know u have to delete them by selecting if you'll color this it will become strong and you will loose transparency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Transparent" isn't a color, so you can't eyedropper it. As Jack says, you need to erase them if you want transparency at those pixel locations.

Comment: @Jack and @Alan Gilbertson -- Ah, Jeez [blush] thanks. Please reveal to no one that I asked this question :-)

Comment: Your secret is safe with me... :-D

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get rid of those pixels is to select them, and then cut them from the image with the [Ctrl]+[X] shortcut.

You can use the Magic Wand to select that contiguous block of pixels with a single click; (sort of overkill for just 3 pixels, but it's a handy tool to get used to). Make sure you've got the following options set...

- Mode: Replace;
- Match mode: RGB Value;
- Tolerance: a value in the order of 0-15 works well in most cases; however, for what you want to do here, you can leave the value as 0 (assuming all those pixels really are white);
- Use all layers: False (doesn't actually matter for a single-layer *.png file);
- Contiguous: True;
- Feather: 0;
- Anti-Alias: False.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the offending pixels on another layer.

You can accomplish this by using the PSP lasso tool, or manually defining the pixels or manually defining the perimeter of the area you want to be "no color" (i.e. transparent).

Once you isolate the pixels or the area, move them to another layer, then either turn the layer off, or delete it altogether.

Best of luck.